# Jquery attributes not clearing on new event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want a modal to show on click of a specific link, and then when it hides I want the attribute from the click that opened it. The following code works perfectly on the first click, but after that it returns attributes from previous clicks also.

```
$('body').on('click',function(e) {
  var $target= e.target;
  $('#my_modal').modal('show');
  $('#my_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    alert($target.getAttribute('data-my-id'));
  })
});
```

[Here is the fiddle demonstrating this.](https://jsfiddle.net/lilbiscuit/5t87ejbu/)

How to I only return the current click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$('#my_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {`

to `$('#my_modal').one('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {`

(i.e. ONE instead of ON).

This will unbind the handler after it runs, so that whenever the click event creates that new handler, the past handlers will no longer exist to make extra function calls.
http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

you can also try add attribute value to modal and use same while displaying on modal close event. Please see below code

```
<a href="#" class="btnlink" data-my-id="101"> Link 101</a><br/>
<a href="#"  class="btnlink" data-my-id="102"> Link 102</a><br/>
<a href="#"  class="btnlink" data-my-id="103"> Link 103</a><br/>

        <!-- modals -->
        <div id="my_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Test Me</h4>
              </di class="btnlink" v>
              <div class="modal-body" id="linkval" data-attr="">
                <p>
            This is only a test.
            </p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                      </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

 $('.btnlink').on('click',function(e) {
  var $target= e.target;
  $('#my_modal').modal('show');
  $('#linkval').attr('data-attr',$target.getAttribute('data-my-id'));
 });

    $('#my_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      alert($('#linkval').attr('data-attr'));
      $('#linkval').attr('data-attr','');
    });
```